If the cleanup function is dependent on a dependency value, how does React trace that?
In this code of React website :
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleMove(e) {
      setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
    }
    if (canMove) {
      window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);
    }
  }, [canMove]);

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={canMove}
          onChange={e => setCanMove(e.target.checked)} 
        />
        The dot is allowed to move
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        opacity: 0.6,
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        left: -20,
        top: -20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      }} />
    </>
  );
}

The useEffect is dependent on the variable canMove. So when canMove is true and the effect just run once and for every pointermove in the browser, the added Event Listener gets triggered. When canMove is false, React should run the cleanup first before the setup.
But the return statement is under condition of canMove which is now false so the control should not enter there. So does React logs the cleanup function when the setup of Effect runs? And if it does so where React stores the cleanup function till the next useEffect gets triggered.

Yes, react keeps a reference to the the cleanup function from the last effect, and calls that. where React stores the cleanup function till the next useEffect gets triggered. Are you looking for what line of code in react's codebase is responsible for this?

Yes  which code performs this : like where does it store and how does it store?

It will be stored in a normal javascript variable, I'm guessing a property of the fiber object. I'll see if i can find the code.


But the return statement is under condition of canMove which is now false so the control should not enter there. So does React logs the cleanup function when the setup of Effect runs?

Yes, react keeps a reference to the previous effect's cleanup function and calls that.

And if it does so where React stores the cleanup function till the next useEffect gets triggered.

The implementation for useEffect (on renders after the first one) is called updateEffectImpl, found here. It calls a function pushEffect, then saves the resulting value to hook.memoizedState. pushEffect creates and returns an object which includes the "create" function. create is the function that you passed into use effect, which may or may not return a cleanup function.
hook.memoizedState = pushEffect(
    HookHasEffect | hookFlags,
    create,
    inst,
    nextDeps,
);

Later, in ReactFiberCommitWork.js, the create function gets called and the destroy function (if any) gets saved as well.
const create = effect.create;
const inst = effect.inst;
destroy = create();
inst.destroy = destroy;

